# Piwik is not tracking some pages of my local website

Tags: javascript, php, matomo

I have installed piwik on my www folder by copying piwik into it.

Pasted the javascript tracking code on separate file lets say piwik.js and placed it in my local project www\myproj\js

My project contains php files,I have edited the file like below:

```
printf(<script src="js/piwik.js"></script>);
printf(</head>);
```

Placed the above statement in almost all the files.

Piwik dashboard tracking most of the files but some files it is not tracking.

I am not sure the exact reason..Please any one help me.

Comment: Probably the relative path `js/piwik.js` is not accessible on your PHP files. all your PHP files are on folder `www\myproj`?

Comment: ya and the js file is in www/myproj/js/piwik.js..The js folder contains other js files also.But other php files can be accessed piwik.js.